# Webscraping in vba - Structure working data & write from left to right cell

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

just registered an account here, and yes i'm a real noob - please be nice to me. Now to my challenge: I am building a web scraper in VBA & have found a code I changed a little to my needs. Everything works perfectly and is actually quite smooth. Now I would like my text that loads into my exel document not to be long, but instead to be wide. I suspect it has to do with ".Offset (I, j)". I've played with it a little bit, but I just manage to ruin everything. Here is my code im usin:

````
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument 'Document object
Dim eleColtr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for tr tags
Dim eleColtd As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for td tags
Dim eleRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Row elements
Dim eleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Column elements
Dim ieURL As String 'URL

'Open InternetExplorer
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
'Navigate to webpage
ieURL = "#"
IE.Navigate ieURL
'Wait
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
 DoEvents
Loop
Set htmldoc = IE.Document 'Document webpage
Set eleColtr = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'Find all tr tags
'This section populates Excel
I = 0 'start with first value in tr collection
For Each eleRow In eleColtr 'for each element in the tr collection
 Set eleColtd = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(I).getElementsByTagName("td") 'get all the td elements in that specific tr
 j = 0 'start with the first value in the td collection
 For Each eleCol In eleColtd 'for each element in the td collection
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(I, j).Value = eleCol.innerText 'paste the inner text of the td element, and offset at the same time
 j = j + 1 'move to next element in td collection
 Next eleCol 'rinse and repeat
 I = I + 1 'move to next element in td collection
Next eleRow 'rinse and repeat

End Sub ```
````

Comment: Can you share the url? Or at least indicate the input format and expected output format along with relevant html? You can include the relevant html using the snippet tool via [edit] (looks like icon with <> on)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have attached the link

Comment: Do you want that entire Details table as it appears on the page but transposed?

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback! yes,I would need all the information

Comment: Can we ignore the headers e.g. "Basic Info"? If not, how do you expect them to appear?

Comment: "Basic Info" - "Basic Info" is not a requirement and yes, we can ignore the remaining headers

Comment: Just a hint: Some years ago, I scraped offers from chrono24 over a longer period of time for a specific watch brand. After some time, they started to block my IP address. I always reset them manually before the next daily readout. If you get the same problem, you can solve it via a proxy pool.

Comment: Hi Zwenn, thanks for the replay! i will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a browser. You can use faster xhr. Grab the table and loop the rows then the columns populating a pre-sized array (be sure to remove the rows where headers are. They can be identified as having `[colspan='2']` in their first `td`). Then transpose the array and write to sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TransposeTable()
    Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, table As MSHTML.htmltable
    'required VBE (Alt+F11) > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library ;  Microsoft XML, v6 (your version may vary)

    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    '  7NXBG2 ;  8QT2E3

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.chrono24.com/watch/8QT2E3", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set table = html.querySelector(".specifications table")

    Dim results(), rowCountToExclude As Long

    rowCountToExclude = html.querySelectorAll(".specifications table [colspan='2']").Length
    ReDim results(1 To table.rows.Length - rowCountToExclude, 1 To table.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).Children(0).getAttribute("colspan"))

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, outputRow As Long, outputColumn As Long, html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set html2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    For r = 0 To table.getElementsByTagName("tr").Length - 1
        Dim row As Object

        Set row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")(r)
        html2.body.innerHTML = "<body> <table>" & row.outerHTML & "</table></body> "

        If html2.querySelectorAll("[colspan='2']").Length = 0 Then
            outputRow = outputRow + 1: outputColumn = 1
            For c = 0 To row.getElementsByTagName("td").Length - 1
                results(outputRow, outputColumn) = row.getElementsByTagName("td")(c).innerText
                outputColumn = outputColumn + 1
            Next
        End If
        Set row = Nothing
    Next

    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub
```

Comment: I am extremely grateful for the prompt response! and I'm sure I'm a noob. But if I use the code I get compile error

Comment: You need to add the appropriate references in the vbe indicated at the top of the code _required VBE (Alt+F11) > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library ;  Microsoft XML, v6 (your version may vary)_

Comment: What is the error message and on which line does it occur please?

Comment: and now, whats really strang (and of course my mistake !!!) i started a new modul and now it workd perfect!!! THANK VERY MUTCH!

Comment: okey so when i try to use the same step but i change the url same page, ex: "https://www.chrono24.com/rolex/mens-air-king-date--5700-very-good-condition-mens-watch--id12873580.htm". i get driving errors "9" - why?

Comment: html is different and now the dimension for rows in results array either too small or too many rows are getting added that should be filtered out.

Comment: sorry if I'm annoying! is there a solution that allows solve this so i don't terrorize you ? thanks in advance

Comment: I will have a look for you

Comment: as you probably understand, the url varie - Forever grateful!

Comment: Answer updated for you. Note that you can use shorter urls if you know the listing id